# How can i integrate Clang in Visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clang

I am new to Clang. Anyone help me to run my project using clang compiler which is developed on VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the underlying tools in `Visual Studio 2008` with any compatible compiler, that is for example Clang, the Intel compiler and a newer version of the MS compiler. Since you also need matching headers and libraries, the easiest way is to install the latest `Visual Studio Community` and edit the `Visual Studio 2008` config files to point to the new environment. The config files are:

- `<VS2008PATH>/VC/vcpackages/VCProjectEngine.dll.config`
- `<VS2008PATH>/VC/vcpackages/AMD64.VCPlatform.config`

I've described the steps in more detail here:
[Visual Studio 2008 with c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302891/visual-studio-2008-with-c11)