# Change (use older) c++ version in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to use an older version in Visual Studio than c++11? A similar question revealed that it is not possible to use a newer version, but I want the compiler to complain when I am using language features that are only available for c++11.

Comment: Simply set the platform tool set in the project properties

Comment: Alternatively, install some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) variant - 4.9 or better; or some recent [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (perhaps thru [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), [mingw](http://mingw.org/), or by installing a Linux distribution). Then compile with `g++ -std=c++98` or `clang++ -std=c++98` .... Don't forget to ask for all warnings & debug info `-Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely disable C++11 features in Visual Studio, you must compile with a toolset old enough that it does not have any C++11 features. The last version of Visual Studio to have no C++11 support was VS2008 (question about that here: [Visual Studio 2008 with c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302891/visual-studio-2008-with-c11)).

To use an older toolset, you must first install that version of Visual Studio, and then modify the "Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset" and set it to the appropriate Visual Studio version. When you compile with Visual Studio 2008 toolset, any C++11 usage will be errors.

Comment: But that requires VS2008 to be installed.

Comment: that's why I said: "To use an older toolset, you must first install that version of Visual Studio" :)

Comment: I get that this "hack" means you can do it from your new IDE, but really this is just saying "no, use an older version of VS"!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true, but, it's the best answer for the question that's asked. If you like the newer IDEs better, or you need the newer one because it has features/plugins that don't support older versions, then it does provide some advantage over simply using MSVC 2008. It would be nice if MSVC would be more flexible/complete with compiler features and backwards compatibility (like gcc), but, it's just not.

Comment: This seems to work. Another solution I came across is using Makefiles to compile.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to disable C++11 features for a Visual Studio project without installing an older MSVC version.

Comment: As my answer states, you can, it's just painful.