# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion, hex, decimal

**Environment :** Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

I am trying to debug Hexadecimal to decimal conversion but unfortunately getting "term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments" this error.Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue ?

**code:**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int stoi;
    int number = 0;

    string hex_string = "12345";
    number = stoi(hex_string, 0, 16);
    cout << "hex_string: " << hex_string << endl;
    cout << "number: " << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stoi` is an integer, why are you trying to call it as a function?

Comment: @VTT if it is not declare it gives an error like ""error C3861: 'stoi': identifier not found"

Comment: You want to use the std::stoi https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol (another reason why using namespace std is wrong)

Comment: @Adderbill no it doesn't - https://wandbox.org/permlink/p0BmWNaYTAaFm8HR

Comment: The support for C++11 (where `stoi` was introduced) is limited at best. You need a  different solution or a different compiler. (Note that if this is a school exercise, you're supposed to do the conversion yourself, not use a library.)

Answer (score 2):

This is why you shouldn't do `using namespace std;`. Get rid of it and fix the program by putting `std::` before everything in the `std` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int stoi;
    int number = 0;

    std::string hex_string = "12345";
    number = std::stoi(hex_string, 0, 16);
    std::cout << "hex_string: " << hex_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number: " << number << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You could also just rename your `stoi` integer to not clash with `std::stoi`, but [it is strongly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to not have `using namespace std;` in your code.

If you can't use `stoi` at all because [Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302891/visual-studio-2008-with-c11) and you can't upgrade to a newer version, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c) for alternatives. But in the long way it would probably be a better idea to install a newer IDE if possible.

Comment: Now the error like 1]error C2039: 'stoi' : is not a member of 'std'
2]error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Comment: What's your version? You need at least C++11 to use `stoi`.

Comment: You should use C++11 or later

Comment: @Blaze I have Microsoft Visual C++  10.0.40219

Comment: @Adderbill in that case you can't use `std::stoi` and will have to use an alternative. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c) for some suggestions, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/10411602) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `stoi` is a function from `string library` you dont redefine stoi as `int stoi`. Delete `int stoi` it would be succeeded.

Complete code like these

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number = 0;

    string hex_string = "12345";
    number = stoi(hex_string, nullptr, 16);
    cout << "hex_string: " << hex_string << endl;
    cout << "number: " << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1] error C2039: 'stoi' : is not a member of 'std' and
2] error C3861: 'stoi': identifier not found, this are the errors if i removed int stoi

Comment: @Adderbill can you editted your publishment with our suggestion, after this we could help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everyone for your response ! 
final code which is debug successfully on visual studio 2008 for conversion of hexadecimal to decimal

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
#include <sstream>

int wmain() {
int binNumber ;
unsigned int decimal;
string hexString = "0x3d"; //you may or may not add 0x before
stringstream myStream;
myStream <<hex <<hexString;
myStream >>binNumber;
cout <<binNumber <<decimal;
return 0;
}
```